# how to send mail faster using javamail api

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

In my scenario I have generated one pdf using jasper report. I have send a mail to my superior with attach that pdf but the mail sending process take more than a minute. So what I do to send my mail with a second, can you help with any coding formate using javamail api. Here I have given my enter mail sending coding structure for your concern. Thanks

```
public boolean sendMailForVacation(String subject, String bodyContent,String emailAddress,byte[] pdfFile,String pdfFileName,String company){
          boolean isMailsent=false;
          final String SMTP_HOST= getText("email.smtp.host");
          final String SOCKET_FACTORY_PORT= getText("email.socket.factory.port");
             final String SMTP=getText("email.smtp.port"); 
          final String MAIL_USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS=getText("email.username");
          final String MAIL_USER_PASSWORD= getText("email.password");
          final String EMAIL_FROMNAME= company;//getText("email.fromname");
          try{
           Properties props = new Properties();
           props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST);
           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",SOCKET_FACTORY_PORT);
           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
           props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
           props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP);
           Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator(MAIL_USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS, MAIL_USER_PASSWORD);
              Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
           Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
           InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress(MAIL_USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,EMAIL_FROMNAME);  
           message.setFrom(from);
           message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(emailAddress));
           message.setSubject(subject);
           MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
                  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                  messageBodyPart.setContent(bodyContent, "text/html");
                  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                      messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                      ByteArrayDataSource baDS=new ByteArrayDataSource(pdfFile,"application/pdf");//application/vnd.ms-excel  
                      messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(baDS));  
                      messageBodyPart.setFileName(pdfFileName); 
                      multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                      message.setContent(multipart);
                      Transport.send(message);
                      isMailsent=true;
          }catch(Exception e){
           LOGGER.error(e);
          }
          return isMailsent;
         }
```

Comment: It takes as long as it takes. You're bound by the network and the receiver's read speed, not by your code. The only thing you can speed up in Javamail is multiple outgoing messages, by sending them all over the same `Transport` instance.

Comment: It won't make your code faster, but it will make it simpler, if you fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).